# SQL Substring function

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following statement. When I don't use the substring function I get over 20 rows selected. When I use this statement I get zero. I'm just wondering what I would need to fix in this statement to achieve the same results.

```
SQL> select * from
  2  (select
  3  sql_fulltext, executions
  4  from v$sql
  5  order by elapsed_time desc)
  6  where substr(sql_fulltext,1,30) like '%table_name%';
```

Comment: Does `table_name` appear in the first 30 characters?

Comment: May be stupid comment, but is the string "table_name" in the first 30 characters of sql_fulltext?

Comment: No it doesn't. Here is the Q I'm trying to solve "2. Display the SQL statements (first 30 characters only) and the number of executions for all SQL commands that have been executed for those SQL statements that include the word table_name.(Hint – Escape clause)"

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(select
  sql_fulltext
, substr(sql_fulltext,1,30) ShortText
, executions
from v$sql
order by elapsed_time desc)
where sql_fulltext like '%table_name%'
```

So select in the full name, and use ShortName for the result.

Comment: There is no need for the derived table, the where condition can be applied directly.

Comment: Agree, @a_horse_with_no_name, but did not want to confuse the issue. Was not sure if golf_pro90 might have it there for a different reason.